Snowflake Invalid Grant
I am getting below response when I try to get Access Token with Grant Type Client Credentials
{
 "data" : null,
 "error" : "invalid_grant",
 "code" : null,
 "message" : "The provided grant or refresh token is invalid.",
 "success" : false,
 "headers" : null
}

Below is my Security Integration
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURITY INTEGRATION my_oauth_client
  TYPE = OAUTH
  ENABLED = TRUE
  OAUTH_CLIENT = CUSTOM
  OAUTH_CLIENT_TYPE = 'CONFIDENTIAL'
  OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://localhost.com' 
  OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS = TRUE;

Note: I am able to get access Token when I use Grant Type as Authorization code as it is asking for Authorzation by opening a window, I am looking for Client Credetials which is Server to Server Authorization
Please point me what I am doing wrong here

The most likely reason for these errors are the scope mismatch or the incorrect grant type being supplied.
Please review this article to get the exact set of steps for configuring the client credentials flow for Snowflake using Azure AD.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-External-OAuth-Token-Using-Azure-AD-For-The-OAuth-Client-Itself

I am getting Invalid Grant for Client Credentials because Snowflake OAuth only support Auth code grant flow
So I am going to use External OAuth

When using snowflake as te Oauth provider, Only the authorization code grant is an option to get the token.
If you wish to get the token using any other grant type, you shall have to use the external Oauth.
Please refer to the following document for configurations:
External Oauth Overview
